# Sending a process id from client to server

Tags: c, server, client

My task is to write a client program that writes a struct with a privateFIFO name (FIFO_XXXX, where XXXX is the pid that we get from the getpid( ) function) to the server. Then, have the server read the privateFIFO name and write a message back to the client. i.e., Read the message and print it on the client side. I am having trouble sending the FIFO_XXXX to the server program and also writing a message from the server back to client.

`client code:`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int main (void)
{

  struct values
  {
    char privateFIFO[14];
    int intbuff;
  }input;

  int fda;  // common FIFO to read to write to server
  int fdb;      // Private FIFO to read from server
  int clientID;
  int retbuff;
  char temp[14];

  clientID = getpid();
  strcpy(input.privateFIFO, "FIFO_");
  sprintf(temp, "%d", clientID);
  strcat(input.privateFIFO, temp);
  printf("\nFIFO name is %s", input.privateFIFO);

  // Open common FIFO to write to server
  if((fda=open("FIFO_to_server", O_WRONLY))<0)
     printf("cant open fifo to write");

  write(fda, &input, sizeof(input));    // write the struct to the server
  close(fda);


  // Open private FIFO to read
  if((fdb=open(input.privateFIFO, O_RDONLY))<0)
     read(fdb, &retbuff, sizeof(retbuff));

  printf("\nAll done!\n");

  close(fdb);

}
```

`server code:`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


struct values
  {
    char privateFIFO[14];
    int intbuff;
  }input;

int main (void)
{

  int fda;  //common FIFO to read from client
  int fdb;  //private FIFO to write to client
  int retbuff;
  int output;

// create the common FIFO 
  if ((mkfifo("FIFO_to_server",0666)<0 && errno != EEXIST))
        {
        perror("cant create FIFO_to_server");
        exit(-1);
 }

// open the common FIFO
  if((fda=open("FIFO_to_server", O_RDONLY))<0)
     printf("cant open fifo to write");


  output = read(fda, &input, sizeof(input));

// create the private FIFO
  if ((mkfifo(input.privateFIFO, 0666)<0 && errno != EEXIST))
  {
    perror("cant create privateFIFO_to_server");
    exit(-1);
  }


  printf("Private FIFO received from the client and sent back from server is: %d", output);

  //open private FIFO to write to client
  if((fdb=open(input.privateFIFO, O_WRONLY))<0)
    printf("cant open fifo to read");
  write(fdb, &retbuff, sizeof(retbuff));


  close(fda);
  unlink("FIFO_to_server");
  close(fdb);
  unlink(input.privateFIFO);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use IPC message Queues. It better and simple. Indeed, This mechanism manages synchronization between read and write operations, concurrent access, ...:

**The Writer Process:**

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <sys/ipc.h> 
#include <sys/msg.h> 

// structure for message queue 
struct mesg_buffer { 
    long mesg_type; 
    char mesg_text[100]; 
} message; 

int main() 
{ 
    key_t QueueKey; 
    int msgid; 

    // ftok : generate a unique OPC key 
    QueueKey = ftok("FIFO_XXXX", 65); 

    // msgget creates a message queue and returns identifier 
    msgid = msgget(QueueKey, 0666 | IPC_CREAT); 

    // Sending Data
    message.mesg_type = 1; 
    printf("Write Data : "); 
    gets(message.mesg_text); 

    // msgsnd : Send message to the queue
    msgsnd(msgid, &message, sizeof(message), 0); 

    // display the message 
    printf("Data send is : %s \n", message.mesg_text); 

    return 0; 
}
```

**The Reader Process:**

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <sys/ipc.h> 
#include <sys/msg.h> 

// structure for message queue 
struct mesg_buffer { 
    long mesg_type; 
    char mesg_text[100]; 
} message; 

int main() 
{ 
    key_t QueueKey; 
    int msgid; 

    // ftok to generate unique key 
    QueueKey = ftok("FIFO_XXXX", 65); 

    // msgget creates a message queue and returns identifier 
    msgid = msgget(QueueKey, 0666 | IPC_CREAT); 

    // msgrcv to receive message 
    msgrcv(msgid, &message, sizeof(message), 1, 0); 

    // display the message 
    printf("Data Received is : %s \n",  message.mesg_text); 

    // IPC_RMID : destroy the message queue 
    msgctl(msgid, IPC_RMID, NULL); 

    return 0; 
}
```

**Remarque:**
Be aware that a process can be both writer and reader. To do this, two message queues must be created for each process. the first allows for example to receive, the second to write. If you really want to separate read / write spaces for each process.